# CSS - Flip Hover effect to happen only once

Tags: html, css

I have a `section` in a website with a `flip-hover` effect. The client has asked if the `flip` can be restricted to one automatic flip from `front-to-back` and then `back-to-front` once the cursor is removed and any future `flips` to only happen by `click`. Basically they don't want the action to keep happening automatically, just on one occasion per site visit. I think they're thinking is it might get a bit annoying if it keeps happening when a user is navigating the site. 
Is this even possible and if so, how do I do this?

Here's the code as it stands -

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,800);
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
}

#whatwedo {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/* Parallax flipping cards - Codepen */


/* *{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
} */

h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.container-fluid {
  /* width: 90%; */
  margin: 0px auto;
  /*  max-width: 80rem; */
}

.cols {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.col-sm-3 {
  /* width: calc(25% - 2rem); */
  /* margin: 1rem; */
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  /* padding: 10px; */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.front,
.back {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  -o-transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1), -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  /* size of box */
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.back {
  /* background: #fff; 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  #cedce7 0%,#596a72 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  #cedce7 0%,#596a72 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,  #cedce7 0%,#596a72 100%); */
}

.front:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  /* background shade - was .6 originally */
  opacity: .;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 0px solid;
}

.container:hover .front,
.container:hover .back {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  -o-transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1), -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
}

.back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  font-size 1rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.inner {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(60px) scale(0.94);
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(60px) scale(0.94);
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-perspective: inherit;
  perspective: inherit;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  /*  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d; */
}

.container .front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  /*   -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d; */
}

.container:hover .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  /* -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d; */
}

.container:hover .front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  /* -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d; */
}

.front .inner p {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

.front .inner p:after {
  content: '';
  width: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: ;
}
```

```html
<section id="whatwedo">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>What we do</h1>

    <div class="cols">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="front">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Brand Identity</p>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
              <div class="inner">
                <p> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="front">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Graphic Design</p>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="front">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Editorial Design</p>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="front">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Brand Guidelines</p>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="front">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Print Management</p>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="front">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Signage</p>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="front">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Creative Direction</p>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="front">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Illustration & Animation</p>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Create class some class and move animation to it.  remove that class by JavaScript and set some class to check if mouserover is happen or not

Comment: Control the animation by JS. Remove the hover attr once done and bind a click event to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you get started.

First works on hover. After that on click :)

```js
var containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container');

containers.forEach(container => {

  container.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    if (!container.classList.contains('flipcomplete')) {
      container.classList.add('flipped');
    }

  });
  container.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    if (!container.classList.contains('flipcomplete')) {
      container.classList.remove('flipped');
      container.classList.add('flipcomplete');

    }
  });
  

container.addEventListener('click', function() {
    container.classList.toggle('flipped');

  });

});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,800);
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
}

#whatwedo {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/* Parallax flipping cards - Codepen */


/* *{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
} */

h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.container-fluid {
  /* width: 90%; */
  margin: 0px auto;
  /*  max-width: 80rem; */
}

.cols {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.col-sm-3 {
  /* width: calc(25% - 2rem); */
  /* margin: 1rem; */
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  /* padding: 10px; */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.front,
.back {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  -o-transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1), -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  /* size of box */
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.back {
  /* background: #fff; 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  #cedce7 0%,#596a72 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  #cedce7 0%,#596a72 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,  #cedce7 0%,#596a72 100%); */
}

.front:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  /* background shade - was .6 originally */
  opacity: .;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 0px solid;
}

.container:hover .front,
.container:hover .back {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  -o-transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1), -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
}

.back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  font-size 1rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.inner {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(60px) scale(0.94);
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(60px) scale(0.94);
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-perspective: inherit;
  perspective: inherit;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  /*  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d; */
}

.container .front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  /*   -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d; */
}

.container.flipped .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  /* -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d; */
}

.container.flipped .front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  /* -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d; */
}

.front .inner p {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

.front .inner p:after {
  content: '';
  width: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: ;
}
```

```html
<section id="whatwedo">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>What we do</h1>

    <div class="cols">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="front">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Brand Identity</p>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
              <div class="inner">
                <p> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="front">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Graphic Design</p>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="front">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Editorial Design</p>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="front">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Brand Guidelines</p>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="front">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Print Management</p>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="front">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Signage</p>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="front">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Creative Direction</p>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="front">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Illustration & Animation</p>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
              <div class="inner">
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi buddy, thanks so much for the answer here yesterday. Funny thing, though, when I try and implement into my text editor files the javascript doesn't work. I've done another Q on it here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/46406549/3521315 - can you spot what might be stopping it?

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly get some information from : [Run CSS3 animation only once (at page loading)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482820/run-css3-animation-only-once-at-page-loading)

I think it's not possible using only CSS. You could add some javacript to toggle an attribute once it's hovered and use it in your CSS a single time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no problem in using jQuery just use the library "jQuery Flip".