# Play CSS animation only once

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

1.div container with animation (transition) when directive (`ng-show` || `ng-if`) display it.

2.Parent div which controlled by an external button (add style property `display: none` or `display: block`)

Have an issue:

How processing animation just once, when 1. - showed, but don't repeat it again if the parent becomes `display: block` from `display: none`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run CSS3 animation only once (at page loading)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482820/run-css3-animation-only-once-at-page-loading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `ng-show/ng-if` is triggered by change of some condition, you can use a `boolean` to determine wheather the display is initial and set it in the same context.

Then you can use `ng-class` to add a class initial to your div and move the css-transition properties.

Like this:

HTML:

```
<div ng-class="{'initial': controller.initial}"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div.initial{
  transition: ...
}
```

JS/Controller:

```
functionThatSetsShowCondition(){
  controller.initial = true;
}
```

Comment: I have solved by myself, your answer closest to my, because my case more complex so I accept your idea, using third var for control animation - it's right way!