# Can i disable a transition after it has once been displayed?

Tags: css, hover, transition, mouseover

is there a possibility to make a transition function once you hover on it and when moving the mouse out and then hovering over it again, not to function any more? so to disable the transition after once played.

thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Sorry, but you're going to need to give a lot more details than that. What have you tried? What are you using? Can you provide a simple, minimal code example of what you want to do?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow :) Please visit [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how to properly ask a question.

Comment: Also, possibly a duplicate of [Run CSS3 animation only once (at page loading)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482820/run-css3-animation-only-once-at-page-loading)

Answer (score 2):

Yes! It is possible by changing the class name of your transition element using javascript when you hover. However, when you hover on the transition element, the javascript function will be called before your on hover style and you won't see the transition even in the first time. To solve this you can change the className in the second time you hover. Following is how I have done it on an element having class name 'demo' that I changed to 'demoover' in the second hover:

```js
var timedHover=0;

function mouseOver() {
if(timedHover!=0){
document.getElementById("demo").className = "demoover";
}
timedHover=1;
}
```

```css
.demo{
     color:red;  
     transition: 1s;
}
.demo:hover{
     color:pink; 
}
     
.demoover{
     color:red;   
}
```

```html
<h1 id="demo" class="demo" onmouseover="mouseOver()">Mouse over me</h1>
```